# I want to get a Javascript array in a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <table id="table_1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</table>



 var Classmates = ["Chris", "Jan", "Thomas", "Julia", "Tess", "Remco", "Kris", "Mark", "Rick", "Sara"];
var Emails = ["chris@gmail.com", "jan@gmail.com", "thomas@gmail.com", "julia@gmail.com", "tess@gmail.com", "remco@gmail.com", "kris@gmail.com", "mark@gmail.com", "rick@gmail.com", "sara@gmail.com"];


for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + Classmates[i], Emails[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
```

I want this array to be shown in a simple html table so it shows the email next to the classmates name.

Comment: Share your attempt

Comment: show us the code.. what have you tried?

Comment: Cycle through those arrays with a single loop, append the `td`s to the DOM. Have you tried like this yet?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I think the down vote is a little bit unnecessary and rude

Comment: Guess people just don't want to help..

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Astonishingly, Stackoverflow encourages us to, I quote, "downvote and move on" instead of asking OP "Hey, what have you tried so far?"

Comment: I edited the post, attempt is now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a string variable and append the html to it and do document.write for that variable.

```
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    output += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + Classmates[i] + "," + Emails[i] + "</td></tr>";
}
document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few improvements that needs to be done

1. For **table**, you need to write the table tag as well
2. For iteration, you can simply use the length of either of the array (improves code by removing hard coding)
3. For showing classmate and email as comma separated, you need to put comma in quotes
4. Start of array is at index 0, hence, to get the number correct increment it by 1 in the document.write statement

```js
var Classmates = ["Chris", "Jan", "Thomas", "Julia", "Tess", "Remco", "Kris", "Mark", "Rick", "Sara"];
var Emails = ["chris@gmail.com", "jan@gmail.com", "thomas@gmail.com", "julia@gmail.com", "tess@gmail.com", "remco@gmail.com", "kris@gmail.com", "mark@gmail.com", "rick@gmail.com", "sara@gmail.com"];


document.write("<table border='1'>");
for (var i = 0; i < Classmates.length; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + (i+1) + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + Classmates[i] +", " + Emails[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
    
document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each array and create a dome node using `document.createNode`.Use `appendChild` to append tr & td to the table

```js
var Classmates = ["Chris", "Jan", "Thomas", "Julia", "Tess", "Remco", "Kris", "Mark", "Rick", "Sara"];
var Emails = ["chris@gmail.com", "jan@gmail.com", "thomas@gmail.com", "julia@gmail.com", "tess@gmail.com", "remco@gmail.com", "kris@gmail.com", "mark@gmail.com", "rick@gmail.com", "sara@gmail.com"];

for (var i = 0; i < Classmates.length; i++) {
  let _tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let _tdClassmates = document.createElement('td');
  let _tdEmail = document.createElement('td');

  _tdClassmates.innerHTML = Classmates[i];
  _tdEmail.innerHTML = Emails[i];
  _tr.appendChild(_tdClassmates);
  _tr.appendChild(_tdEmail);
  document.getElementById('studentTable').appendChild(_tr);

}
```

```html
<table id='studentTable' border="1px solid black"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define all variable at top and crearte new elements and build a new table. Later append the table to the body.

```js
var classmates = ["Chris", "Jan", "Thomas", "Julia", "Tess", "Remco", "Kris", "Mark", "Rick", "Sara"],
    emails = ["chris@gmail.com", "jan@gmail.com", "thomas@gmail.com", "julia@gmail.com", "tess@gmail.com", "remco@gmail.com", "kris@gmail.com", "mark@gmail.com", "rick@gmail.com", "sara@gmail.com"],
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    td, th,
    i;

th = document.createElement('th');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'));
tr.appendChild(th);

th = document.createElement('th');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('e-Mail'));
tr.appendChild(th);

table.appendChild(tr);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(classmates[i]));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(emails[i]));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score -1):

Give the table an id. in my case i use 'table_1'.
and also include jquery library.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
$('#table_1').append('<tr>');
$('#table_1').append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
$('#table_1').append("<td>" + Classmates[i], Emails[i] + "</td>");
$('#table_1').append('</tr>');
    }
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged or used in question hence not a valid answer

Comment: It may work, so I didn't downvote, but it's awfully ugly and not optimized. You're traversing the DOM 4 times in _each loop_ and building the same jQuery object 4 times uselessly, that makes a total of 44 costly operations instead of 1. And you don't need jQuery for that. On second tought, downvoted.

Comment: I used jQuery object 4 times for get the idea. you can optimize the code anyway you want. shame on you for downvoting.